# What is the best way to implement handwritten character recognition on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, character, image-recognition, handwriting

What is the best way to implement handwritten character recognition in iPhone?

I'm thinking as follows:

First, taking a picture of handwritten character.

Second, recognizing image of handwritten character, and then outputs a text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use neural networks because neural networks are good in classification but the answer depends on probability..
But if you can identify a certain logic in your characters, you can use fuzzy logic because then the answer will be more accurate than in neural networks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in step 2:

"2. Second, recognizing image of handwritten character, and then outputs a text."

This is not a completely solved problem in image processing. In fact, saying "not completely solved" is a pleasant way of indicating that the problem is insanely hard. It's one thing to say "use a neural net" or "try a genetic algorithm," and another to actually implement something that works, and that would outperform the current state of the art.

As a start, I would recommend reading the following book from cover to cover:

**Character Recognition Systems** by Cheriet, Kharma, Liu, and Suen

It's the book I usually recommend because it's reasonably up to date, it covers a large variety of techniques, and it also makes fairly clear that this is not a solved problem. There is an older and much more expensive book by Bunke that is also a great resource.

There are **partial** solutions to handwriting recognition. If you can pick a very specific application, such as recognizing numerals written on a check, then you simplify the problem a bit. Many ATMs these days have good OCR to recognize the amount of a check, but again, this is a highly constrained problem.

If you investigate neural networks, then I hope you never have to debug one once it's trained.